# Hardcoding dns adresses in dependance to network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dhcp, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to save permanently dns addresses. 
According to [link](https://superuser.com/questions/677343/how-to-make-name-server-address-permanent-in-etc-resolv-conf) I added in

> /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

proper line and in my home network everything works great. 
Problem is that when I am at my University, I am not able to connect with Internet with these dns addresses and I have to manually comment everytime this line in dhclient.conf. Is it possible to set permanently dhcp addresses but only for specific network?